# Setting Entity ID in Domain Driven Design

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, uniqueidentifier

Regarding the creation of Entity object instance, identified by a unique ID as opposed to a value object, would it be correct to define the unique ID in the Application layer of the architecture.

Traditionally in a database driven design the unique ID would be created at the database level with a sequence or an autonumber. As the persistence layer should be abstracted from the domain in domain driven design, so we are not dependant upon any data store proprietary mechanism.

**So my question: is it correct, or common practice, to generate a global ID at the application layer when creating an instance of an entity object as it's unique ID.**

Answer (score 0):

Often this is done at the database layer to avoid collisions / race conditions which are difficult to achieve at the application layer without significant complexity.

If you are willing to use things like [GUID/UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as your unique identifiers, you can generally generate them without worrying about synchronization, but they are fairly unpleasant identifiers to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah the point of DDD is to not depend on one specific store type. So it might be a database or LDAP for instance. A transaction is needed in the application layer when calling the database layer to avoid race conditions, it is not the database itself that avoids race conds. unless working with a stored procedure of course. This is, as you state, a non-issue when dealing with global unique IDs